# Display text from class on external website

Tags: php

I am trying to get the contents from a `<span>` element on an external website and display it, however it is not displaying.

The link to the website where I am getting the contents from is https://www.roblox.com/catalog/119916949/Midnight-Blue-Sparkle-Time-Fedora

Here is the `<span>` element:

[image]

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.roblox.com/catalog/119916949/Midnight-Blue-Sparkle-Time-Fedora");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query2 = "//span[@class='text-robux']";

$entries2 = $xpath->query($query2);

$price2 = $entries2->item(0)->textContent;

echo $price2;
?>
```

Comment: Your `loadHTMLFile` method has a different URL to which you've put in your question. Which is it?

Comment: So can you tell me where this is failing?  Is it loading the external file correctly, or is this an xpath issue?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Sorry, that was a small typo

Comment: @EatPeanutButter That's what I can't figure out. I'm guessing it has to be an issue with the code as the element is on the external website

Comment: Do some basic debugging and figure out if your $doc object actually contains the contents of the external website

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I can confirm it does

Comment: does it work if you change the xpath to use the id of the element?  Also, if you print the DOM can you see the information in there?  It could be that the value is being loaded by AJAX after the page has loaded, and your loading of the file is happening before AJAX has triggered

Comment: @gabe3886 Would it simply be `$query2 = "//span[@id='item-average-price']";`?

Comment: @TheCodesee yes, it should just be that simple.  And if the page is built correctly, you don't have to worry about other classes of the same name messing up your results (which could be what's happening

Comment: @gabe3886 I've tried updating it but the same issue is still occurring. If the value is loaded by AJAX after the page has loaded, what can I do?

Comment: @gabe3886 I've checked and the value does not show up when viewing the source code (CTRL + U) but it does with Inspect Element and when viewing the page

Comment: @TheCodesee it sounds like the value might be loaded by AJAX then, and done so to stop people scraping the content of the page.  Different technical challenge

Comment: @gabe3886 Is there any way possible to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The charts are built by javascript. `loadHTMLFile` loads only html. You can check what content is actually loaded by disabling javascript in the browser's devtool settings, or by fetching data with curl.

Data itself is loaded by AJAX from https://www.roblox.com/asset/119916949/sales-data.

It is JSON, so to get average price you can do simple json_decode:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(
    file_get_contents("https://www.roblox.com/asset/119916949/sales-data")
);
echo $data->data->AveragePrice;
```

Comment: Ah, this explains it! Thank you very much :) If you don't mind me asking, how did you find that URL?

Comment: [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), but you can use any other sniffer. I believe one can get the url even from the static code analysis, but I am too lazy to do so.